# How i can access an image with a random name from the name of the folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, web

I have a folder with one file and i need access to it using only the Folder name. This is basically the struct:

- Folder

  - File.ext (Random name)

For example:
When i go to "http://example.com/Folder/" i need to redirect me to "http://example.com/Folder/File.ext".

I tried with ".htaccess" but not achieved what I need:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^/Folder/$ /Folder/*.ext
```

Exists some regular expression to solve this problem with htaccess? 
or some other solution to this problem?

**Aclaration: the folder only contains one file, and this file have a random name.**

Comment: You could put an index.php into it, use scandir and redirect to or read and output the desired file.

Comment: moreover, you can rename all them  to index :)

Comment: Thanks, but scandir when it only have one file? what is the best method to solve this? i need the best performance, this file is called millions times.

Comment: if you need the best performance and your are on Linux, you can make à link from this file to a fixed name - and if you are not on Linux, use a "scandir PHP script" to create the .htaccess file with the name of the file